# Google Analytics get data of User report from API

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to generate a report like "user Report" (it's on  Audience => User Explorer) with the session duration by day.

How can I get this data using the Google Analitycs API using PHP ?

I'll try dimension = ga:sessionDurationBucket and metric = ga:sessionDuration. But I can't generate the same report.

Comment: You'll have better luck getting a good answer if you can share your code. Do you encounter an error? Do you get data back but not the data you want? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Did you give a try to the PHP quickstart?** It shouldn't be too difficult to tweak to what you want:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php

```
  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  var $result = $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
```

As for how to create a custom dimension, see this example:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#dimensions_and_metrics

```
//Create the Dimensions object.
Dimension browser = new Dimension()
    .setName("ga:browser");

// Create the ReportRequest object.
ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest()
    .setViewId("XXXX")
    .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
    .setDimensions(Arrays.asList(browser))
    .setMetrics(Arrays.asList(sessions));
```